# VBA While Loop freezing data uplink, need to run Sub once a second

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, do-while

I'm needing to run a sub once a second while also receiving data from a feed.  The function looks at the data in the cells, determines if conditions are right, and if so sends a command to the trade server (where my data feed is coming in).  This issue is once I run the loop, the While Loop freezes my cells in excel, making the program execute without updating.

```
Dim timeremaining As Integer
timeremaining = Range("E7").Value
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Do While timeremaining > 5
    Endowment
    Sleep 1000
Loop
```

I've tried the setting a timer (OnTime) approach, and creating a function to run it a set number of times, yet both functions freeze my data feed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656(office.11).aspx) method in VBA

For example: 
         Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))